# LINQ and multiple aggregates

Tags: c#, linq

I have code similar to this:

```
decimal total1 = 0;
decimal poTotal = 0;
foreach( var record in listOfRecords)
{
   total1 += record.Price;
   if ( record.HasPo){
     poTotal += record.PoTotal;
   }
 }
```

This works fine but I'd like to know how to perform multiple aggregates using linq without excessive coding for groups etc...  is there a simple way that doesn't require scanning the list of objects each time?

I know I could do this:

```
var poTotal = listOfRecords.Where(r=> r.HasPo).Sum(r.PoTotal);
```

But that requires scanning the entire list and I if I'm to aggregate multiple values I only want to loop/scan one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Aggregate` method, but I don't think it will be more clear than a simple `foreach` loop you already have:

```
var totals = listOfRecords.Aggregate(
    new { Total = 0m, PoTotal = 0m },
    (a, r) => new {
        Total = a.Total + r.Price,
        PoTotal = a.PoTotal + (r.HasPo ? r.PoTotal : 0m)
    });

Console.WriteLine(totals.Total);
Console.WriteLine(totals.PoTotal);
```

Comment: thanks, I have not used the `Aggregate` method, I assume that anon class is the aggregate object that is referenced as `a` in the `(a,r)`?   This is what I was looking for, something to consider at least.

Comment: Yes, `a` is an anonymous type instance you declare as initial `seed` value to hold all your aggregates.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* also do something like this:

```
decimal poTotal = 0;
decimal total = listOfRecords.Sum(record => {
    if (record.HasPo) {poTotal +=  record.PoTotal;}
    return record.Price;
});
```

But I'm not saying you *should*. As MarcinJurasek says, the simple `foreach` is clearest in this case.

Comment: @TMcKeown _"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."_ --Brian Kernighan

Comment: i didn't say I would use that, I said I liked the trickery.. that just means I like the hack.  Why do you think I have the code in the current form?  I am always comparing new techniques.

Comment: and that quote is as old as the hills..  simplicity is the most important tenet in software design to me.